# Combine Lightning with Javascript libraries (React, Angular2)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning, angular

We're rewriting our old Salesforce site (based on VF pages) for the new era. We have a lot of logic in our controllers that we want to shift to client-side.
We want to create a Salesforce community based on a Javascript framework (probably React or Angular2), while incorporating Lightning Components (dashboards and such).
How should we build it, first the Lightning pages and glue the JS in on top? Or build the JS app and glue the Lightning Components in?
What kind of interesting problems will we run into?
I realize that this is a very open-ended question. I guess what I'm going for here is to try and learn from others' past (and probably painful) experiences.

Comment: I suggest you Google this subject extensively before making any assumptions. The Lightning Locker Services is by design intrusive. See e.g. [LockerService and Lightning Container Component: Securely Using Third-Party Libraries in Lightning Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/02/lockerservice-lightning-container-third-party-libraries-lightning-components.html).